# как увеличить дату с помошю метода AddDays(); в цикле -->DateTime i DateOnly

Tags: c#, .net

```
public void schedule()
{
    
    //DateOnly dateOnly = lastWorkDayDate(); 
    DateOnly dateOnly1 = new DateOnly();
  

    //int restDayCounts = restDayCount();
    //string lastWorkDay = lastWorkDayDate().ToString();
    //string vacationdate = VacationDate().ToString();
    //string curentmonth= CurentMonth().Month.ToString();

    //List<int> scheduleList = new List<int>();

   

   

    while (true)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(dateOnly1.AddDays(3));
    }


}
```

Comment: Покажите свой код.

Comment: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе._

Comment: Метод `AddDays` возвращает _новое_ значение. Старое значение при этом остаётся неизменным. Нужно написать `dateOnly1 = dateOnly1.AddDays(3);`

Comment: спасибо большое всем кто ответил!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменил ответ с учетом комментария. Рабочий код. Но советую почитать теорию по языку, что бы лучше понимать как такие вещи делать

```
DateOnly date = new DateOnly(2022, 06, 28);

List<DateOnly> scheduleList = new List<DateOnly>();
```

Записываем в список результаты. Условие выберите сами.

```
while (date.Year < 2023)
{
    date = date.AddDays(3);
    scheduleList.Add(date);
}
```

Выведите на экран:

```
foreach (var s in scheduleList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: походу я не только новичок, но еще и тупой новичок :)) у меня был написан вопрос, Но небыл написан код,  но после вставки кода, исчез вопрос , код остался :)) нет, я хотел немножко другое.. я хотел взять дату допустим: 01/06/2022. и к е той дате в цикле прибавлять значение т.е вот так: 01.04-> 04.04--> 07.04--> 10.04 и.т.д ну я типо делаю програму которая высчитывает график работников, которые работают по сменна, раз в 3 дня :) и по идеи это программа должна высчитывать график этих рабочих :) UPD: Лист в данном случи лишний, в него собираюсь прописывать уже готовые данные (если будут готовы :)

Comment: Исправил ответ. Если подходит, пометьте как решение вопроса